# Create smooth surface plot of an irregular spaced circular grid using TChart in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, teechart

Update:
Just tried with TeeChart 2014.10.140220 and the problem I showed in the screenshots is no longer present.
I guess it was a bug in calculating / displaying the chart, which has been fixed.

I'm writing analysis tooling using Delphi XE (32bit) and **TChart Pro v2011**.
I'm developing on Windows 7 64bit with a 3.2Ghz quadcore with 8GB memory.
When testing this plot for development, I have about 6GB of memory free.

What is being analyzed is a circular surface (diameter of 300mm) for which the height has been measured in 134 rectangular grids of 35*52 points. These grids are not equally spaced, and the points within the grids are not evenly distributed, although both deviations tend to be small. Of course the grids at the edges of the circle are not complete as the edge goes right through them. The points are actually the measured values of rectangles of 1mm by 3mm (yes, they overlap).

The user needs to see a 2D plot (x and Y axis only) of a coloured circle where the colour indicates the height at each point. This should be maintained when zooming in and the center of the circle should be at `x:y = 0:0`.

I have tried to use several of the offered surface series, but none are capable of correctly plotting this surface (strange artefacts and (random?) interpolation occurs) and all add a Z axis, which is undesired.

When I try to draw each point as a rectangle with a colour, the plotting itself takes more than a minute (when you click, you want an image on screen right away, not after waiting seconds let alone minutes).

As a workaround, I'm currently using a `TPointSeries` where I colour each point. On the initial view of the chart this looks OK-ish, but when the you start to zoom in you will see all the points separately which is harder to see and also incorrect.
Also, due to the pixel size of the points, they will overlap incorrectly.

Is there a way in `TChart` to correctly draw this surface?

Here is an example of what I want to get (this is actually a pointseries, but the plot was made small enough to see it as a surface):

[image: Desired view]

However when zooming in the "surface" breaks into the respective points.
[image: Problem of TPointSeries]

I tried using a TContourSeries as suggested (using random data). When viewing the the plot in it's initial state it all looks like it is ok, but when you zoom in you see holes appearing, which should not happen.
I added some timing measures to show it indeed takes seconds to display plot. I typically need to display multiple plots at the same time. Zooming in requires more time than the initial displaying.
This plot is created using 1 TContourSeries per grid.

[image: TContour seems OK, but it takes long to display]

[image: Zooming in on TContour shows holes in the series.]

Comment: I don't know about TChart 2011, but an IsoSurface simply with 3D turned off sounds exactly like what you're after

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful that's a 2D chart with TContourSeries and solid Brush.Style, e.g.: Series1.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;.

Comment: @deColaman if thats not what you need, please add an example image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gunter & Narcis: I tried both series as you suggested, however for both I get an out of memory error. When using the point series I do not get this error. I'll try to add images and info on the hardware I use later.

Comment: I can not believe that it takles so long to draw the "points" as a rectangle on a canvas.